# Button titleLabel set to hidden YES, reappears on touch

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

In a view controller I have set up the following code to initially hide a button array group:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for(UIButton * noteButtonItem in noteButtonArray){
        noteButtonItem.titleLabel.hidden = YES;
        //NSLog(@"Title is %@", noteButtonItem.currentTitle);
    }
}
```

From the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *noteButtonArray;
```

And attached via IB

The initial hide works fine, but when ever I "touch" a button (in the simulator), the titleLabel doesn't stay hidden.

What is going on behind the scenes? 
Is there a way to make them stay hidden until hidden is set to YES?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`UIButton` instances can have different configurations depending on their state (states described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState)). If you want to hide the button's title label in all states, you could make use of `setTitle:forState:` and set its title to `@""`, or you could change the alpha property of the color to `0.0f` with `setTitleColor:forState:` so it becomes transparent when the button is in the states chosen.

Comment: Yeah, if you look at UIButton's documentation, or header file, you'll notice that many things having to do with its title/titleLabel have a "forState" parameter. You often enter weird territory when you directly write to the titleLabel property instead of using a setSomething:forState: / setSomethingForState: method.

Comment: After some research on I have
`code` [noteButtonItem setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:100.0 green:100.0 blue:100 alpha:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[noteButtonItem setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:100.0 green:100.0 blue:100 alpha:0.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; `code`

in place of 

`code` noteButtonItem.titleLabel.hidden = YES; `code`

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the tracking methods ot make sure it stays hidden even after it is "touched". This is from the UIControl class reference:

Tracking Touches and Redrawing Controls

- – beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:
- – continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:
- – endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:
- – cancelTrackingWithEvent:
- tracking  property
- touchInside  property